# How to run a function with parameters with in a bash script

Tags: shell

I trying to run a function outside of my script. Example test.sh:

```
DAYS=10
IP=1.2.3.4

Main {
   functionName ${DAYS} ${IP}
   }

 functionName() {
   echo $1
   echo "$2"
   }
```

from command line I'm trying to run the scripts function with different parameters

```
./test.sh functionName 4 "1.3.4.5"
```

Having trouble getting it to work so any ideas would be great thanks

Comment: Functions must be defined before called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the function, $1 is the argument passed to the function, not the argument passed to the script.  Just do:

```
DAYS=${1-10}    # set DAYS to first argument, defaulting to "10"
IP=${2-1.2.3.4} # set IP to 2nd argument, defaulting to "1.2.3.4"

Main() {
    functionName ${DAYS} ${IP}
}

functionName() {
    echo $1
    echo "$2"
}
Main
```

Answer (score 1):

If you `source` your script, then the functions will be available in your current shell:

```
. ./test.sh
functionName 4 "1.3.4.5"
```

Downside is that any code in the sourced script which is not in a function will be run.  You can avoid that by (in the sourced script) doing a test like:

```
if [[ $0 == test.sh ]] 
then 
    Main
fi
```

which might be why you have a Main?  By the way, why are you using global variables?  Why not declare them inside Main (using `local`).

Comment: I'm just updating a script that was written by someone else so just following the same flow